# Enhanced ecommerce - not recording all the transactions

Tags: enhanced-ecommerce

I've have implemented the Enhanced ecommerce code. I'm tracking transactions, items, order ID, etc... The problem is that it isn't recording all the transactions I have registered in my ecommerce platform. When I check my platform information with GA information, I missed more than 50% of transactions in GA. For example: If I have 34 orders in my platform, in GA I only have 14 orders.

Comment: welcome to SO, if you provide your code attempts, links etc so far then the community are more inclined to help that than 'give me code' without evidence of effort. That way they can help many more people.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry!

Comment: <script>ga('create','UA-13307338-1');ga('require','ec');ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': 'DCP-J562DW','name': 'DCP-J562DW','category': 'Transferencia','price': '82.00','quantity': 1});ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {'id': '26209','affiliation': 'brother','revenue': '102.17','tax': '17.73','shipping': '2.44'});ga('send', 'pageview');</script> 
 <iframe width='1' height='1' frameborder='0' src='https://tbs.tradedoubler.com/report?organization=1817659&event=302268&orderNumber=26209&orderValue=102.17&currency=EUR'></iframe>